# What is the proper way to set Content-Type: multipart/form-data with boundary

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http-headers, httprequest

I have a HTTP Post request for uploading files. Backend accepts `multipart/form-data`.

If I don't set  `Content-Type`, browser sets `Content-type` as `multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7lUUqJiDDPnxLRTs`. It works fine.

But if I set Content-Type as `multipart/form-data` or
`multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7lUUqJiDDPnxLRTs`. It doesn't  work.

```
headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data' ); 
return this.http.post(`${this.domain}/v1/topics/Demo/excel`, file, {headers: headers, params}         ) as Observable<any>;     }
```

How can I properly set multipart/form-data with boundary